# Replace nan values in a square matrix

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am using `numpy` for the first time.

I have a square matrix (158 by 158). I want to replace any `NaN` values on the diagonal of the matrix with the median value of the diagonal. Any off-diagonal values I want to be zero.

The code I have written is not working,

```
cov_martix = np.cov(np.transpose(coeff), rowvar=False)

# any nan's on the diagional are replaced by the median value of the diag
# any nan's off the diag are replaced with zero
diag = np.nanmedian(np.diag(cov_martix))
cov_martix = np.fill_diagonal(cov_martix, diag)
cov_martix = np.nan_to_num(cov_martix)
```

The problem is the `np.fill_diagonal` line, after running that line `cov_martix` becomes `None`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`numpy.fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) as per [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html):

> This function modifies the input array in-place, it does not return a value.

hence produces `None`. You are not supposed to reassign it back to the array.
Also, instead of replacing `nan` values in diagonal with `median` of diagonal, you are replacing all diagonal elements with `median` of diagonal.

Could you try this:

```
>>> diag = np.diag(cov_matrix)
>>> np.fill_diagonal(cov_matrix, np.nan_to_num(diag, nan=np.nanmedian(diag)))
>>> cov_matrix = cov_matrix * np.eye(cov_matrix.shape[0])
```

For example:

```
>>> cov_matrix

array([[ 2.,  0.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  4.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0., nan,  3.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  2.,  1.]])

>>> diag = np.diag(cov_matrix)
>>> np.nan_to_num(diag, nan=np.nanmedian(diag))
array([2., 2., 2., 1.])

>>> np.fill_diagonal(cov_matrix, np.nan_to_num(diag, nan=np.nanmedian(diag)))

>>> cov_matrix
array([[2., 0., 4., 4.],
       [1., 2., 4., 1.],
       [1., 0., 2., 3.],
       [2., 1., 2., 1.]])

>>> cov_matrix = cov_matrix * np.eye(cov_matrix.shape[0])
>>> cov_matrix

array([[2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
cov_martix = np.fill_diagonal(cov_martix, diag)
```

to

```
np.fill_diagonal(cov_martix, diag)
```

edit: Also remove `cov_matrix=` in the last line

Comment: thanks that does fill the diagonal. The only issue is it populates every diagonal element, I need to populate only values on the diagonal that are nan